# Where is Spark Streamings state stored?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm using Spark Streaming with `updateStateByKey()` and `mapWithState()` functions, but I do not clearly understand where state is saved. Does state saved on HDFS? Or it's in-memory storage? How fault tolerance is guaranteed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spark Streaming currently has two implementations for stateful streams. One is the older `PairRDDFunctions.updateStateByKey` (Spark <= 1.5.0) , which uses a [`CoGroupedRDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD) to store the state for each key. The newer version called `PairRDDFunctions.mapWithState` (Spark >= 1.6.0) uses a [`OpenHashMapBasedStateMap[K, V]`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/util/StateMap.scala#L84) to store the internal state. Both of these are the *in-memory implementations*

Both of these stateful streams use [checkpointing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) as a mechanism for *persistent* fault tolerance. A checkpoint location can be HDFS or Amazon's S3 where the data is persisted every interval which is either defined by the user using `DStream.checkpoint` or will be defaulted to (batch interval * constant). You are obligated to specify a checkpoint directory when using stateful streams.

Comment: Does the directory of the checkpoint have to be in HDFS or S3? If I give a local address, do the workers save on their own part or do they send it to the driver?

Answer (score 0):

The state is stored in checkpoint directory which is specified during a start of Streaming Context. For more information about checkpointing and a fault tolerance it is providing please refer to [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing)